# How to download all file/sources (in sources tool) in a website?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

[screenshot in sources tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcMpI.png)

Hello, I want to ask about sources tool. I use microsoft edge as my browser. Now, I download the file in sources tool manually one by one, but it must be wasting time. Is there a way to download all file in sources tool like in the screenshot? Thank you.

I expect that I can download all the file in one time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no suitable method or extension in Edge to achieve your needs. In [this discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675894), an extension is mentioned, but it is not listed in the Edge extension store. Therefore, I think this requirement cannot be achieved.